# What is Vec4b, MatObj.ptr in opencv ?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

My question is based on the following code.

```
Vec4b *rv = mMat.ptr<Vec4b> (50);
```

I don't understand what Vec4b means. I know about Vec4i which means line segment coordinates. So similarly I tried to find what it contains.
The below code

```
std::cout<<rv[1]<<std::endl;
```

gave an output:

> [8, 7, 10, 10]

I dont know what those parameters mean. Surprisingly it showed outputs for parameters greater than four. Eg., rv[4],rv[5] and so on.

So **I really dont't get what Vec4b does. Also the mMat.ptr.** I Could not find good online sources about Vec4b and Mat.ptr.

Any clarification about what the first code does would really be helpful in enlightening my mind.

Comment: Vec4b is a datatype: 4 byte values (unsigned char value in [0,255]). Vec4i is just 4 integer values. Which one you use should depend on the type/elements that are stored in your matrix! If you store Vec4b values (for example RGBA image data for values between 0-255) and you access that with `<Vec4i>`, then you might get some memory access errors.

Comment: @Micka Thanks for your info. But still I don't get it. 4 byte values of a particular row in the image ? why do we use that ? That piece of code is from an image segmentation algorithm (MeanShift). I am trying to understand that.  Have you any references for Vec4b ?

Comment: as far as I know, `mat.ptr(y)` gives you a pointer to the y-th row of the matrix. Since the matrix doesn't know what kind of elements are in it, you must specify that with the template parameter `<Vec4b>` or `<float>` or `<unsigned char>`, etc. So In your example, you assume a matrix with 4 channels, each of them has 1 byte size (for example RGBA pixel), and you access a pointer of the 50th row. If you want to access pixel `(23,50)` you could now call `Vec4b pixel = rv[23]`. Now `pixel[0]` is blue channel value, `pixel[1]`green, `pixel[2]` red and `pixel[3]` the alpha channel (for BGRA data).

Comment: @Micka: Thank you. Now, you have made it more interesting to me. In your example, you mentioned pixel (23,50),  the pixel 23 would be taken from the 50th row of the image. Am I right ? I have an image of dimensions 320 x 240. If so, in the 50th row, I would be having 320 pixels. Or am I wrong ? I should only be able to put till pixel(319,50). In my question, I used rv[1], which means the first pixel of the 50th row. Right ? But I am able to get Vec4b values till rv[10000]. Shouldn't it till be 319 ? This is where I don't understand.

Comment: in C++ you can try to access any memoryposition. Whatever is at `rv[10000]` might be still part of your image (for example the next row if the matrix is continuous) or "filling bytes" or maybe any other memory entry. So you just look at that RAM address and interpret the next 4 bytes as a Vec4b. That's what makes C++ tricky sometimes (finding errors) but is part of it's efficiency, too. Try `yourmatrix.at<Vec4b>(row#, column#). Afaik in Debug mode this will give an exception if you're outside the matrix bound.

Comment: in other words: have a look at C++ arrays: `rv[10000]` means that you take the address `rv`, add `10000*size of a Vec4b` to that address. Read the next `size of Vec4b` bytes and interpret them as a `Vec4b` value. If that's out of your array size, openCV doesn't check hat.

Comment: @Micka. Thank you. It's a lot of information for me. But I am very poor in debugging and finding the address location of a variable in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **So I really dont't get what Vec4b does.**

As can be seen from [OpenCV's API](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec), it's defined as follows:

```
template<typename _Tp, int n> class Vec : public Matx<_Tp, n, 1> {...};
...
typedef Vec<uchar, 4> Vec4b;
```

In other words, it contains 4 `uchar` (`unsigned char`) values. The `Vec` class is commonly used to describe pixel types of multi-channel arrays, e.g. `CV_RGBA`.

> **Also the mMat.ptr.**

[`Mat::ptr()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ptr) returns a pointer to the specified matrix row.

---

So, for your code,

```
Vec4b *rv = mMat.ptr<Vec4b> (50);
```

After this, `rv` will be a pointer with type `Vec4b` that pointers to the `51`-th row of `Mat mMat`.

---

**Edit:** As all `Mat`'s data are continuous, after all pixels of current row, e.g. using big index in `rv[index]` (for `index >= mMat.cols`), you will get data from other rows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I understood what basically Vec4b is. I have got another question. rv[1] in my code snippet means 1st pixel in the 51st row. So, in a 320 x 240 image, should not I be able to get Vec4b of pixels till 320 ? But I am able to get till rv[10000]. If I am wrong about rv[1], then what does it mean ?

Comment: @Karthik_elan No, `rv[1]` is the 2nd pixel in the 51st row (0 index based).

Comment: @Karthik_elan And for a `320x240` image, you should be able to get `rv[0-319]` in total 320 pixels.

Comment: yeah, I am sorry. I meant 2nd only.

Comment: then how could I get Vec4b values till 10000 ? and when I exceed with one more zero at the end, the code gets crashed.

Comment: @Karthik_elan There are only 320 pixels in `rv`, why do you want to get `10000`? You mean the `10000`-th pixel of the whole image??

Comment: Before knowing about the working of Vec4b in my code, I was playing with more arguments inside rv[]. I was getting Vec4b parameters as output **for more than 320 pixels**. I should not be able to get that. right ?

Comment: @Karthik_elan Actually you will get output for more than 320 pixels. Because all `Mat`'s data are continuous, after 320 pixels, you will get data from other rows.

Comment: Yes. I was in 51st row. Out of total 76800 pixels, I was having around 60000 pixels available. So it worked. When it exceeded,my code got crashed. Now I understood.